# List of countries that includes how much of the workforce is employed by the government

Tags: government, employment

Where can I find a list of European/World countries by government workers per capita or as a percentage of total workforce? I can't seem to find it on Eurostat. It would be interesting to see the effects of this policy and find a correlation between count of government workers and how "rich" the country is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a pretty [good chart](https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/sites/9789264075061-en/05/01/index.html?contentType=&itemId=/content/chapter/9789264061651-13-en&containerItemId=/content/serial/22214399&accessItemIds=/content/book/9789264075061-en&mimeType=text/html) showing the breakdown by OECD country showing data from 1995 and 2005:

[image: Public Employees by Country]

That can be compared with the GDP rankings of each of these countries [found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_OECD_countries_by_GDP_per_capita) to get a pretty good picture of the relationship (if any) that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank You! It is surprise for me that there is less government workers in Greece and in Poland than in USA

Comment: @JurisMalinens The first (serious) effort to find out the exact number of government workers in Greece started in July 2010 and a year later a number of 768009 was announced (out of ~11mil). The number seems small, but it was about a million (or more) before the debt crisis, it was drastically reduced when several obsolete or near obsolete gov. agencies were closed down and I'm not 100% certain if the current number includes seasonal part time workers or not (their number may be significant, tourism is our main industry).